# Intellij slowing down, routinely reaching max heap size then prompting to quit

Tags: android, macos, intellij-idea

IntelliJ slows to a crawl. Hardly can type without 1-2 delay between keys. I've updated the heap-size. I'm running on about 2GB RAM on my Macbook Pro. Ever since it's been slowing down. I've increased the heap-size  everywhere to no avail as follows:

- in the info.plist (mac)
- when it prompts to quit due to max heap
- under preferences in compiler for java
- android dx compiler

Really frustrated since it's never done this to me before. Just now, i hardly coding mostly browsing the web and IntelliJ hit its heap-size and prompted to quit.

Any suggestions?  Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check that you are using the [latest release](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) or [EAP version](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP).
2. Rename the [following folders](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) to start with all the default setting, clean caches and no third-party plug-ins:

   > ```
   > Settings: ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12
   > Caches: ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea12
   > Plugins: ~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea12
   > ```
3. If the problem persists, [submit a bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) and [upload CPU/Memory snapshots to the FTP](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-192). Attach `idea.log` (`Help` | `Reveal Log in ...`) to the reported issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off Github  (under Settings > Version Control) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, increasing VM did not work, just delayed the symptoms a little longer,  to resolve it, I had to invalidate Caches via File > InvalidateCaches/Restart.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html